# How can I calculate the bmi of a nested list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is the list >

```
person_data = [
              ['John', 84.9, 184],
              ['Ryan', 81.8, 177],
              ['Bobby', 86.1, 190],
              ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180],      # Name, Weights, Heights
              ['Pete', 92.2, 188],
              ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
              ['Jane', 72.0, 166],
              ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]
              ]
```

This is what I can do so far.

```
BMI = [person_data[0][1]/((person_data[0][2]/100)**2)
      for i in person_data]
```

The result is

```
[25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983,
 25.07679584120983]
```

However, I want the list comprehension to loop through all the person's weight and height. Is only doing it for the first nested list. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the iteration variable `i` anywhere. Each item is a person (list of attributes), so you need to do something like this:

```py
BMI = [person[1]/((person[2]/100)**2) for person in person_data]
```

Result:

```py
[25.07679584120983,
 26.109993935331477,
 23.850415512465375,
 43.20987654320987,
 26.086464463558173,
 27.530556544440483,
 26.1286108288576,
 19.547325102880652]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!